# How to convert date's format from Jul 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800 to mm/dd/yyyy in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I tried to use monent.js to convert it

```
   const newDateResult=moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

but the data type I got is a String

what I need is I want to convert it to MM/DD/YYYY and the data type still need to be "date"

Comment: A date is a date. Dates don't have a format, they have a date. Date *strings* have a format.

Answer (score 0):

Your moment code is on the right track, but the output of `format()` is always `String`. Try adding `.toDate()` instead to convert your result to a Date.

```
moment("Jul 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800").toDate()
```

Comment: TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16___default(...)(...).format(...).toDate is not a function. but I got this ....